# Changing the default command-line shell in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe

Suppose I (or any running process) wanted to launch a shell in Windows (7) and issue a command, there are a number of options available. For example, one could:

1. Bring up the start menu, type `cmd`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
2. Launch the command prompt via a shortcut;
3. Bring up the command prompt in a third party tool (such as Launchy), or;
4. Issue some commands in Windows' **Run** tool (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), which launches the prompt, issues the command and then returns

All of the above methods will (by default) launch `cmd.exe` (usually located in the `Windows\System32` directory).

Recently I have started to favor alternate command line shells, such as Microsoft's very own PowerShell. However, what frustrates me most about using these tools, is that I seem to have to go out of my way to launch commands through them by default.

Is there any way that I can **replace the default behaviour of running `cmd.exe` with another shell**, such as PowerShell or Cygwin? Not only so commands that I might issue from the start menu or a launcher will run in that shell, but if other applications want to open a shell, it will open in said default shell.

To be clear, it'd be nice if there was some clean way to approach this (i.e. a registry setting or configuration option somewhere, rather than simply replacing the executable file).

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for but better: https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/

Comment: Windows' Run tool does **not** involve cmd.exe in any way. Whatever you type in there is simply passed to a function, ShellExec, which is part of shell32.dll. As evidence, the "dir" command works within the command prompt environment, but it won't work at the Run prompt. That's because "dir" is not a separate executable - it is a command implemented within cmd.exe. And "dir" is not understood by ShellExec.

Comment: It is possible to put in a registry setting to have another program run in place of `cmd.exe`: I am not sure it is a good idea, however. [See this article](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/how-to-replace-windows-10-system-programs-with-non-microsoft-apps/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> .1. Bring up the start menu, type `cmd`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>;

Type `powershell` instead.

> .2. Launch the command prompt via a shortcut;

Change the shortcut's target.

> .3. Bring up the command prompt in a third party tool (such as Launchy), or;

IIRC, Launchy just uses shortcuts from Start Menu. Some other tools are hardcoded to run `cmd.exe`.

> .4. Issue some commands in Windows' Run tool (Win+R), which launches the prompt, issues the command and then returns

"Run" *does not* open a shell, `cmd` or any other, unless you specifically asked for it by typing its name. It runs the given program directly (AFAIK, by using [`ShellExcuteEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)).

The black window is a [Windows Console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console). It *does not* mean there's `cmd.exe` running inside; it could have *any* console program. *(Exactly the same is with Unix terminals; they could have any program running, not necessarily a shell.)*

---

That said, some programs might still honor the [`%COMSPEC%` environment variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ComSpec).

Comment: I guess my problem is with other applications primarily. For example, in Explorer, hold `Shift`, right click and then click `Open command window here`. By default, it opens `cmd.exe`. What is telling Windows to do that, is that the `%COMSPEC` environment variable?

Comment: @Bauer: That right click is set in the registry, the commands associated with file type "Folder" or "Directory" (later is filesystem folders only), or by an Explorer extension.

Comment: @Richard: It would be `Directory`. ("Open command prompt" wouldn't make any sense for non-filesystem folders.)

Comment: @Bauer: In Windows Vista and newer, it's probably hardcoded to the Explorer shell (but try changing `%COMSPEC%` anyway). In XP and older, it's either a command verb in `Registry\HKCR\Directory\shell` or an Explorer shell extension, like @Richard said.

Comment: @Gravity: <pedantic>PowerShell (to name one example) is not limited to file system directories: `cd HLKM:\software\classes` works fine.